# Eslint find but skip .tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, lint, tsx

I would like start using eslint on my .tsx files.
My configuration looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
    'env': {
        'browser': true,
        'es2021': true
    },
    'settings': {
        'react': {
            'version': 'detect'
        }
    },
    'extends': [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
    ],
    'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    'parserOptions': {
        'ecmaFeatures': {
            'jsx': true
        },
        'ecmaVersion': 12,
        'sourceType': 'module'
    },
    'plugins': [
        'react',
        '@typescript-eslint'
    ],
    'rules': {
        'indent': [
            'error',
            'tab'
        ],
        'linebreak-style': [
            'error',
            'unix'
        ],
        'quotes': [
            'error',
            'single'
        ],
        'semi': [
            'error',
            'never'
        ]
    }
}
```

If I have a file with extension of .ts and run this command:
`yarn eslint ./src/components/Frame.ts`
... I can have a list of linting errors.

If I change the extension to .tsx and run this command on it:
`yarn eslint ./src/components/Frame.tsx`
... I have no message at all. No error or warnings or anything. It is like the file would be
valid.

In my VSCode I have ESLint extension. It is working. It highlights the issues. As I know this extension use the same .eslintrc file so the configuration should be good.
[image]

Can you give some idea why the configuration is working with extension and why it is not working in terminal?

Comment: maybe `.eslintignore` ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: would be nice, but I've removed already to be sure

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you run es-lint
Currently `@typescript-eslint` doesn't check .tsx by default you must specify extensions that need to be checked for example

```bash
yarn eslint --ext=ts,tsx src
```

This command will search for all files ending with `.ts` or `.tsx` in the src folder and `@typescript-eslint` will work as expected with `.ts` or `.tsx`

```bash
yarn eslint src/**/*.ts src/**/*.tsx
```

This command will search for all files ending with `.ts` or `tsx` in src folder but, `@typescript-eslint` will only work on `.ts` and will ignore `.tsx`

```bash
yarn eslint ./src/components/Frame.tsx
```

This command you was trying to run will work the same as the second command `yarn eslint src/**/*.ts src/**/*.tsx` but, it will search for `./src/components/Frame.tsx`